# Using the last inserted record's ID as a foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I am making a database which links together two tables via the primary key of the first table. The one with the primary key which links the two is created first but how do i make the second record get the ID of the record I just created?

```
create table Person
(

    Person_ID int IDENTITY(100000,1) primary key,
    First_Name varchar(20) not null,
    Last_Name varchar(20) not null,
)

create table Employee
(

    Employee_ID int identity(100000,1) primary key,
    Person_ID int references Person(Person_ID),
    Employee_Type varchar(10)
)

insert into Person(First_Name, Last_Name) values ('Michael', 'Chu');

insert into Employee(Person_ID, Employee_Type,) values (????????, 'Admin');
```

I've had a look at the 'last()' function but not really sure how to utilise that. Other then that, I have no idea. Can someone help me out or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: i'm using sql server

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
create table Person
(

    Person_ID int IDENTITY(100000,1) primary key,
    First_Name varchar(20) not null,
    Last_Name varchar(20) not null,
)

create table Employee
(

    Employee_ID int identity(100000,1) primary key,
    Person_ID int references Person(Person_ID),
    Employee_Type varchar(10)
)

DECLARE @myID AS INT

insert into Person(First_Name, Last_Name) values ('Michael', 'Chu');

SET @myID = @@IDENTITY

insert into Employee(Person_ID, Employee_Type,) values (@myID , 'Admin');
```